# Is there such a thing as a super programmer?

Tags: productivity, experience

Have you come across a super programmer? What identifies him or her as such, compared to "normal" experienced/great programmers?

Also. how do you deal with a person in your team who believes he is a super programmer? Both in case he actually is or if he isn't?

**Edit**: Interesting inputs all round, thanks. A few things can be gleaned:

A few definitions emerged. Disregarding too localised definitions (that identified the authors or their acquaintance as super programmers), I liked a couple definitions:

1. [Thorbjørn's definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-super-programmer/14059#14059): a person who does the equivalent of a good team consistently for a long time.
2. Free Electron, linked from [Henry's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-super-programmer/14395#14395). A very productive person, of exceptional abilities. The [explanation](http://www.randsinrepose.com/archives/2005/03/20/free_electron.html) is a good read.

   > A Free Electron can do anything when it comes to code. They can write a complete application from scratch, learn a language in a weekend, and, most importantly, they can dive into a tremendous pile of spaghetti code, make sense of it, and actually getting it working. You can build an entire businesses around a Free Electron. They’re that good.

   Contrasting with the last definition, is the point linked to by [James](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-super-programmer/15017#15017) about the myth of the genius programmer ([video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/MythGeniusProgrammer.html)). The same idea is expressed as [egoless programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/egoless-programming-you-are-not-your-job.html) in rwong's comment. They present opposite opinions as whether to optimise for such a unique programmer or for a team.

These definitions are definitely different, so I would appreciate it if you have an input as to which is better. Or add your own if you want of course, though it would help to say why it is different from those.

Comment: Yes, and his name is [John Carmack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Carmack).

Comment: I have a list of 4 [Free Electrons](http://www.randsinrepose.com/archives/2005/03/20/free_electron.html) on a small piece of paper locked in a draw in my desk.

Comment: If 'super programmer' == 'genius programmer' click_this http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/MythGeniusProgrammer.html

Comment: See Jeff's response on [egoless programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/egoless-programming-you-are-not-your-job.html).

Comment: I'd just like to add a thought from The Mythical Man-Month book, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month, a research paper was cited that indicates a great programmer multiple times better than an okay one. I don't recall all the details but obviously there's a lot of value in someone who can produce on a team, orders of magnitude more than others.

Comment: Yeah, he's either Sergey Aleynikov or  John Carmack

Comment: Super Programmer === Jon Skeet

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would consider the term "super programmer" only for those who can do work that usually requires a team of good programmers, and do it *consistently* for a long time.

This goes both for writing high quality code (documentation, tests etc) and solving very difficult problems requiring a lot of knowledge and talent to solve.

But it requires a high performance on all accounts for a long time.  For those who write tons of code nobody can understand and maintain, the term is not applicable.

How to deal with?  If you truly *have* such a person then do all you can to provide the scaffolding needed for the person to excel.  This means moving irrelevant stuff out of the way, and provide the resources the person needs.  Please note that I've found that very high performers tend to be humble.

It is, unfortunately, much more likely that you have a person who *thinks* he is a super programmer and isn't.  The way to deal with those is in my experience to make their performance measurable.  "FindBugs may not find any problems", "All code must have tests corresponding to the use cases", "Peer review".

If the code is truly hard to understand, consider weekly meetings where the not-so-super programmer explains any code the code he's written since the last meeting that anybody can request *anonymously* to have explained, and anybody can reject *anonymously* to have accepted in the code base for it to be unmaintainable.  Then at least you have shared the mindset and allowed for future maintainers to veto a piece of code.  This will also strongly indicate to the programmer which kind of code will trigger him having to do extra work.

(EDIT:  The reason for the anonymous bit, is to avoid having the not-so-super programmer retaliate upon those who oppose him).

Comment: Excellent points, except for the anonymous input. If the team is to truly unify, and the "super-programmer" understand whether he actually measures up to the definition, they'll need to learn each others' strengths, weaknesses, to work together for the success of the team and the software, and to build trust. It's a matter of opening themselves to the criticism of others (as is done to a certain degree here) for one to find and correct their short-comings as a super-programmer.

Comment: @Huper, the anonymity is to avoid this getting personal in the beginning.  If you believe you are superhuman, you might not take too well to criticism (or this question would not have been asked in the first place).

Comment: @Thor, it's already personal when you're dealing with what someone believes about himself. Anonymity makes trust far more difficult to develop. Team members have to trust that they can be honest, that criticism is welcome, and that important opinions are out in the open.

Comment: Would a super programmer find it easier or more difficult to explain code to a junior programmer? If the gap is big explanation may be difficult. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @Muhammad, given that my definition is that a super programmer writes clean, maintainable code with good documentation, which even a junior programmer can understand (except for very complex algorithms which is less frequently needed in Java due to the things available in the runtime, so I do not consider them).  I would think that it would be as easy, but maybe take longer, to explain to a junior programmer.

Comment: Sometimes a Super Programmer can also have a fragile ego/diva behaviour and knowing where the criticism comes from would likely start some conflict in the team, dragging down the SP's productivity. While I agree that people problems are best dealt with in an open and honest manner, if you've deadlines to hit,  the anonymous option is good. Once the pressure is off, you can review properly in a project debrief.

Comment: @Alkarouri: if you agree with Thorbjørn's definition (or anyone's) for super programmer, please include it in your question. Otherwise, the scope of this question will be too broad.

Comment: "If you truly have such a person then do all you can to provide the scaffolding needed for the person to excel." Unless you're their manager then this is wrong, wrong wrong. You do everything humanly possible to become this person's friend, understand how they work, and absorb as much information you can from them. Then... you break out a ps3 and a case of beer.

Comment: @rwong: the question is now changed to reflect the two definitions I liked. Should restrict the question somewhat.

Comment: I am still thinking about the idea that anyone can have code explained or rejected. Wouldn't that make the code move slower than needed? I mean, if I have a team of 7 people (including the super programmer), and 3 other programmers understand his code then that is good enough for the product. Having only one against it seems like a waste of developer's time.

Comment: @Muhammad, the idea is not to make the code move slower, but to raise the bar for whatever is acceptable, as you have a problem with unacceptable deliveries.  There is nothing like "please fix this" repeatedly to teach that you might as well do it the first time anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A superprogrammer is any person who can generate code faster than a speeding compiler, more powerful than a recursive function, and able to leap over FIFO stacks in a single bound.

The way you deal with a person in your team who believes he is a superprogrammer is by exposing him to his only weakness - sunlight.

Comment: @Chetan: What is a FIFO stack?

Comment: @Chetan: this is an unhelpful answer. Perhaps you haven't worked with programmers who are just so incredible, you start to wonder if you're worthy at all.

Comment: A superprogrammer should live in the cloud and provide a public API for his *Mind Query Language*.

Comment: @rwong first-in first-out stack, also known as a queue.

Comment: @mathepic: if you can call a queue a stack, does it mean that LIFO and FIFO are the same thing? *(to paraphrase Lincoln)*

Comment: @rwong uhh, no....

Comment: @Chetan compilers don't code. Anyway this isn't making much sense.

Comment: Haha, sorry guys, I had forgotten one word (edited in). I hope you guys got the reference though! (it was a lame joke :D)

Comment: @Chetan: somebody should have figured out the correspondence between sunlight and kryptonite by now:) I personally appreciated your answer, even though it is not strictly speaking technical.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the person to write a chapter of himself/herself in the [Coders at Work](http://www.codersatwork.com/) style. Submit it to a publisher. If it gets rejected, then the person is not a super programmer.

Comment: Is the converse of your statement true? (If it is accepted, can you assume that he/she is a super programmer?) I think this could use clarification.

Comment: I lost any respect I might have had for the author of that book as soon as I read that he was once the "architect of a Java-based transactional messaging system". Oh, well, at least he had the sense to quit that job.

Comment: @Dan Moulding: As long as he shuts up and lets the programmers he's interviewing in that book do all the talking, I don't care what he claims. (I just bought that book and am looking forward to reading it. Hope it's as good as I think it is). =)

Comment: The idea is good, but publishers tend to accept _famous_ programmers rather than super programmers. Correct?

Comment: @Alkarouri: if *super* has the same meaning as in *superstar*, then yes, being a super-programmer means being famous, too.

Comment: @mathepic: it raises the entry barrier by so much that the individual will stop thinking about becoming a super programmer. Therefore, there is no need to think about the converse.

Answer (score 2):

There are those who can produce more output than others.

There are those who can produce output with a lower defect rate than others.

Those who can CONSISTENTLY produce more output, with lower than normal defect rates, might be worthy of being called as Super-Programmer.

Being known of or thought of as such is usually only apparent to an enlightened manager with the benefit of hind sight.

Somebody who things they ARE a super-programmer probably has a big ego and thinks they are good. That does not make them good.

Attitude <> Ability.

Answer (score 1):

Super programmer: a person of above-average intelligence with a strong dedication to programming. I'm talking about a person who spends a lot of his/her time programming, doesn't quit easily and is determined to solve a particular problem. This person rarely goes to sleep if there is a pending problem/bug. Super programmer writes effective, fast and reliable code.
Super programmer has an extensive and in-depth knowledge of at least one programming language (and technology), is skilfull in a few others and can quickly learn anything else that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you come across a super programmer? What identifies him or her as such

From the **programs/projects that have create**, the source code of it, the study that have done.

> believes he is a super programmer

As you say he believes it, this is very difficult to make him not to believe it. The worst think is that that person have been stop to be better programmer because he is think that is all ready is super, and he stop the evolution of him. What worse than that in programming. Anyway, you can always ask for proof... and ask him with whom he/she compare him self to make the assumption that he/she is super.